# Ошибка при "vagrant up" в ubuntu, что не так?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

VirtualBox, Vagrant и Ansible есть.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну он же говорит тебе, что VT-x в биосе отключён. Включи.